# What distributions can I simulate with this stochastic process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, convex-optimization, matrix-equations, constraints

For fun, I am trying to use a two-step stochastic process to simulate an existing distribution $\text{P}(x_i) = p_i > 0$ on some discrete set $x_1, ..., x_n$. The process is as follows.

1. Pick an element $x_i$ with probability $1/n$.
2. With some probability $d_i < 1$, "drop" $x_i$ and go back to step #1. Else, select $x_i$ as the "returned" element.

Define $\text{P}'(x_i)$ to be the probability that this process returns $x_i$. I want to know two things:

- what distributions $\text{P}$ can be matched using this stochastic process, and
- how do I characterize these distributions?

Specifically, I am seeking the necessary and sufficient conditions for a distribution $\text{P}$ such that some $d_i$ exist for which $\text{P}$ and $\text{P}'$ are the same distribution.

---

**Edit: all math below this point is based on an incorrect expression for $\text{P}'(x_i)$.**

I have made some progress. The probability of the stochastic process returning a particular element $x_i$ is the probability that it gets selected and returned in the first iteration; or that any $x_j$ gets selected ($j\neq i$), but then dropped, on the first iteration--and then $x_i$ gets selected and is returned; etc. This is expressed as follows.

$$\text{P}'(x_i) = \frac{1}{n}(1 - d_i)\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \left( \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right) \sum_{j \neq i}d_j \right)^k$$

For this to converge to some probability, it must be true that $((n-1)/n)\sum_{j \neq i}d_j < 1$ (since the sum is an infinite geometric series). This puts a constraint on each $d_i$.

If we assume that the $d_i$ are picked to satisfy this constraint, then, for all $i$,

$$\text{P}'(x_i) = \frac{1}{n}(1-d_i)\left(1 - \frac{n-1}{n}\sum_{j\neq i}d_j\right)^{-1}.$$

If we set $\text{P}(x_i) = \text{P}'(x_i)$ for all $i$, then rearranging the above equation yields the following linear equations for each $d_i$:

$$\text{P}(x_i)(n-1)\sum_{j\neq i}d_j - d_i = n\text{P}(x_i) - 1.$$

Since we can solve each linear equation for $d_i$, we can get additional constraints $0 \leq d_i < 1$, and then solve for $\sum_{i\neq j}d_j$. This yields, for each $d_i$:

$$\frac{n - \frac{1}{\text{P}(x_i)}}{n - 1} \leq \sum_{i\neq j}d_j < \frac{n}{n - 1}.$$

---

From what I have done above, I see that I have a set of $n$ linear equations with $n$ unknowns--but I also have some additional inequalities to satisfy which I do not know how to handle. I am unsure how to proceed from here. Is this some convex optimization problem I'm unaware of? If anyone has any pointers, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Your expression for $P'(x_i)$ is incorrect.  You want to compute $$P'(x_i)=P[\mbox{pick $i$ on round 1} | \mbox{do not drop on round 1}] = \frac{P[\mbox{do not drop on round 1}|\mbox{pick $i$ on round 1}]P[\mbox{pick $i$ on round 1}]}{P[\mbox{do not drop on round 1}]}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate any probability mass function $(p_1, ..., p_n)$ this way.

Fix $(p_1, ..., p_n)$ such that $p_i\geq 0$ for all $i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i = 1$.  Define $p_{max} = \max_{i \in \{1, ..., n\}} p_i$.  Fix $c$ as any real number that satisfies $c \geq p_{max}$ and note that $c>0$.   Define:

$$ d_i = 1-p_i/c \quad, \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\} $$
Then clearly $d_i \in [0,1]$ for all $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$, so these are valid probabilities. Further, $d_i<1$ for at least one $i \in\{1, \ldots, n\}$ (since not all the $p_i$ can be zero).

We now show this choice of $(d_1, ..., d_n)$ works: 
Since $d_i<1$ for at least one $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$, there is always a positive probability of terminating on each given round.  Since all rounds are independent, the number of rounds is geometrically distributed and so the rounds terminate with probability 1.

Fix $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$. Let $Q(i)$ be the probability that your process terminates on item $i$.  Then
\begin{align}
Q(i) &= P[\mbox{pick item $i$ on round 1} | \mbox{keep what we pick on round 1}]\\
&=\frac{P[\mbox{keep what we pick on round 1}|\mbox{pick item $i$ on round 1}]P[\mbox{pick item $i$ on round 1]}}{P[\mbox{keep what we pick on round 1}]}\\
&= \frac{(1-d_i)(1/n)}{\sum_j (1/n)(1-d_j)}\\
&= \frac{1-d_i}{\sum_j (1-d_j)} \\
&= \frac{p_i/c}{\sum_j (p_j/c)}\\
&= p_i 
\end{align}

#### Examples

Choosing $c=p_{max}$ makes the process terminate the fastest.

1) $(p_1, p_2, p_3) = (1/3, 1/3, 1/3)$.

Let $c=p_{max} = 1/3$.  Then $d_i=0$ for all $i$.

2) $(p_1,p_2,p_3) = (1/2, 1/3, 1/6)$.

Let $c=p_{max} = 1/2$.  Then 
\begin{align}
d_1 &=1 - (1/2)/(1/2)=0\\
d_2 &= 1-(1/3)/(1/2) = 1/3 \\
d_3 &= 1-(1/6)/(1/2) = 2/3
\end{align}

Comment: I looked at your comment, as well as your answer. I'm confused about how $$Q(i) = P[\mbox{pick item $i$ on round 1} | \mbox{keep what we pick on round 1}].$$ Once I can understand this, I see that everything else follows neatly. (Also, great examples.) $Q(i)$ seems to only consider the first round. I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: The same experiment is performed on each round, so we only need consider round 1.  Formally we have (by the law of total probability): 
$$Q(i) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \underbrace{P[\mbox{pick item $i$ on round $k$}|\mbox{terminate on round $k$}]}_{\theta}P[\mbox{terminate on round $k$}] = \theta $$ where $\theta$ is the same for each round $k$, so we might as well just define it for round 1.

Comment: I see now! The formal definition did the trick for me. I greatly appreciate your time, and have accepted your answer.